# Group by changing boolean value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have the following SQL question:

```
SELECT station_id, filling_station_status,date_created ,
  case when filling_station_status="FREE" then 0
      else 1 end  as status  
FROM efahrung.electric_station_time_status 
where station_id=11
```

In my table have a column filling_station_status. 
It can be "FREE" or "IN_USE".

I want to group elements so, that if the filling_station_status is changed (from "FREE" to "IN_USE") it will create a date range in my case, date_created.
In the next change again from ("IN_USE" to "FREE") it creates a new date range.

Thanks for a suggestions.

Comment: Please be more specific about what your question/issue/problem is... Do you want to add a new column to the database table? or do you just want a SQL query that generates this new date range as output ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: provide some sample data? will help us a lot

Comment: Now i have the following view: [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Q8v.png[link] and i want to have something like that: [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/HrUUD.png[link]

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: id is a primary key. in this statement i dot' use it

Comment: I'm really busy with work right now or I would have already done it.. i can look at this in a few hours if no-one answers it by then :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need SQL query to generate date range in output, then try this:

```
Select s.station_id, 
    Coalesce(e.filling_station_status, s.filling_station_status) fillingStationStatus, 
    case e.filling_station_status 
      when "FREE" then 0 else 1 end status,
    s.date_created startDate,
    e.date_created endDate
From efahrung.electric_station_time_status s
   Left Join efahrung.electric_station_time_status e
       On e.station_id = s.station_id
          and s.filling_station_status = 'IN_USE'
          and e.filling_station_status = 'FREE'
          and e.date_created =
               (Select Min(date_created)
                From efahrung.electric_station_time_status 
                Where station_id = s.station_id
                   and date_created > s.date_created)
```